# Is there any Python function/method to rearrange dataframe in a specific way?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe with below shape

[image]

My goal is to rearrange above dataframe like below

[image]

In above process, I want to give total number of rows in the final dataframe as input. In above case it is 4.

I tried below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dat = pd.DataFrame({'COL1' : ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "T", "Y", "U", "D"], 'COL2' : [3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 56, 7, 5, 5]})
dat_array = np.array(dat)
dat_array.reshape[2, :]
```

However this gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I would also like to know if/how I can move opposite way. Means, given the second dataframe I should also be able to get back the first dataframe.

Any help and pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df1 = (df.assign(row = df.index %4, col = df.index // 4)
 .pivot(values = ['COL1','COL2'],index = 'row', columns = 'col')
 .sort_index(axis = 1, level = [1,0]))
 
df1.columns = np.char.add('COL', np.arange(df1.shape[1]).astype(str))
df1.index.name = None
df1

  COL0 COL1 COL2  COL3 COL4 COL5
0    A  3.0    G   4.0    D  5.0
1    S  4.0    T  56.0  NaN  NaN
2    D  5.0    Y   7.0  NaN  NaN
3    F  2.0    U   5.0  NaN  NaN
```

Using siuba:

```
from siuba import mutate, _
from siuba.experimental.pivot import pivot_wider


(df >>
  mutate(col = _.index // 4, row = _.index % 4)>>
  pivot_wider(names_from = _.col, values_from = _[_.COL1, _.COL2],
              names_vary = 'slowest'))

  row COL1_0  COL2_0 COL1_1  COL2_1 COL1_2  COL2_2
0    0      A     3.0      G     4.0      D     5.0
1    1      S     4.0      T    56.0    NaN     NaN
2    2      D     5.0      Y     7.0    NaN     NaN
3    3      F     2.0      U     5.0    NaN     NaN
```

---

R code:

```
df %>%
   mutate(col = (row_number() - 1) %/% 4, row = (row_number() - 1) %% 4)%>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = c(COL1,COL2), 
               names_vary = 'slowest')

# A tibble: 4 × 7
    row COL1_0 COL2_0 COL1_1 COL2_1 COL1_2 COL2_2
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     0 A           3 G           4 D           5
2     1 S           4 T          56 NA         NA
3     2 D           5 Y           7 NA         NA
4     3 F           2 U           5 NA         NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to accomplish it with a custom routine. Below, I added an example for your provided data:

```
df <- data.frame(COL1=c("A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "T", "Y", "U", "D"), 
                 COL2=c(3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 56, 7, 5, 5))

final_nrow <- 4

# grab the respective indices
df_slices <- lapply(1:ceiling(nrow(df)/final_nrow), 
                              function(x) df[(((x-1)*final_nrow)+1):((((x-1)*final_nrow)+1)+(final_nrow-1)), ])

# cbind the generated slices into one data.frame
new_df <- do.call(cbind, df_slices)
```

EDIT: I recognized you changed the topic from an R question to a Python question.

Comment: Thanks. That is great. I just thought that having this in Python would be more helpful to me as rest of the codes are written in Python.

Comment: The tag was changed 5 minutes before this response was made. Thus rendering the solution irrelevant. If the solution had been made prior to the tag change then the solution would be valid to the first question. But that is not the case here